# Why will my MEAN app only (partially) run when I set the Angular build directory to /src/ instead of /dist/?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, heroku, mean-stack

I'm following Heroku's [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mean-apps-restful-api) to create a contact list using the MEAN stack (Heroku's running example [here](https://tranquil-shore-75468.herokuapp.com/)). I'm able to deploy it to Heroku and it works there. But when I run it locally on my machine, the browser (Chrome 67.0.3396.87 on macOS High Sierra) only displays a `"Cannot GET /"` message.

I believe it's related to how the Angular build directory `/dist/` referenced in line 12 of [server.js](https://github.com/chrisckchang/mean-contactlist-angular2/blob/master/server.js) does not exist (as far as I can tell). The beginning of `server.js` looks like this:

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongodb = require("mongodb");
var ObjectID = mongodb.ObjectID;

var CONTACTS_COLLECTION = "contacts";

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Create link to Angular build directory
var distDir = __dirname + "/dist/";
app.use(express.static(distDir));

// Create a database variable outside of the database connection callback to reuse the connection pool in your app.
var db;
```

I looked into it and found that Angular [deletes](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/4293) the `/dist/` directory upon `ng serve`. I also found that there is a flag `--delete-output-path` whose default is `true`.

I set the `--delete-output-path` flag to `false` in `.angular-cli.json` as recommended by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49607197/where-to-specify-delete-output-path) as well as in `/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json`. Despite those changes (trying to set the flag in one file, or the other file, or both files at the same time), I'm still getting the `"Cannot GET /"` message and the `/dist/` directory still doesn't appear to be there.

The only way I've been able to even run part of the app is to change [server.js](https://github.com/chrisckchang/mean-contactlist-angular2/blob/master/server.js)'s line 12 reference from `/dist/` to `/src/`. This allows [/src/index.html](https://github.com/chrisckchang/mean-contactlist-angular2/blob/master/src/index.html) to begin loading at localhost:5000/ (the browser displays the text "Loading..." as specified in line 16 of index.html) and gets the contacts API up and running at localhost:5000/api/contacts/. But the Angular components (the list of contacts that is the purpose of the tutorial) don't load. Maybe because I changed the build directory to a totally different location.

Is there something with the `/dist/` directory that I'm missing? Or does my issue with getting the app to run locally have nothing to do with `/dist/` at all?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you don't have a way of handling requests to the route '/' since the line:

```
app.use(express.static(distDir));
```

only ensures that all bundled files generated in your "dist" folder are accessible when your index.html requires them, but you still have to serve the index.html itself. When using the MEAN stack one normally would do something like this:

```
app.use ('/api', yourApiRouter);
//and for everything else let the client-side routing handle the route:
app.get ('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(distDir + 'index.html');
}
```

I recommend to use the native "path" module to join your __dirname with your "dist" folder and your index.html location rather than simple concatenation.
You can use an arrow function instead of a callback when using app.get function if you are using ES6

Comment: Hi Omar! Thank you so much for your answer. When I try to handle requests to '/' as you suggested, the browser displays this message: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/myFilePath/mean-contactlist-angular2/dist/index.html'
    at Error (native)`
I thought it might be a problem with not having a leading `.` before the path but it seems like using __dirname should prevent that. Do you know what might be causing the ENOENT error?

Comment: I'm just guessing here: have you run ng build command and checked if the dist folder is actually being generated? If this is not the case could you please provide some code?